# C++, MFC MDI, activate specific tab

Tags: tabs, mfc, mdi

I have an MDI MFC app.

I want to activate the correct tab if the user tries to open a document twice.

I iterate my CMultiDocTemplate to check if I have the same document open. so I can find out if the same document already exists but I can't find a way to "activate" the correct tab.

Comment: Do you really need this? And I would question even why check if you have the same document open. MFC already does this for you. You actually can't open the same file twice (unless you can somehow fool it, eg opening it from a different share- name or drive mapping). And it indeed activates the document's window (at least in the MDI children case - I didn't test with tabs).

Comment: Hi. 
this is my first MFC MDI app. Maybe my approach is very wrong. 
What I have is online data (documents).
When the user want to view a specific data, I create a new document, and request the data from the server. 
I try to "open" the document and override the open function but i couldn't find the correct way. In that case the MFC would know if the "file" is already opened.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to iterate all your views in order to find the one you'd like to activate. Here is the way to do it:

```
CMDIChildWnd *pChild = (CMDIChildWnd*)GetActiveFrame();  
CDocument *pDoc = pChild->GetActiveDocument();           
POSITION pos = pDoc->GetFirstViewPosition();
while (pos != NULL)
{   
    CView* pView = GetNextView(pos);
    if (viewToActivate)  
        pChild->SetActiveView(pView);                 
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but in this part of the code, you call GetActiveDocument. Maybe the view I want to activate is not for the active document. 

I iterate all open views and find the one I need to activate and use the pChild->SetActiveView(pView) but the tab is not activated. 

the solution I found but I don't like it is to get all tabs groups (maybe is more than one) and then activate the tabs one by one until the GetActiveDocument returns the opened document I want to activate

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
void V10_ActivateMDIFrameFromDocument(CDocument* pDocument)
{
    if (pDocument != NULL)
    {
        // Find the first view
        POSITION pos = pDocument->GetFirstViewPosition();

        if (pos != NULL)
        {
            CView* pView = pDocument->GetNextView(pos);
            if (pView != NULL)
            {
                 CFrameWnd* pFrame = pView->GetParentFrame();
                 if (pFrame != NULL)
                    pFrame->ActivateFrame();
            }
        }
    }
}
```